# What is the /media/myname/SSH2013-09-16 directory for?

Tags: mount, directory, umount

I noticed today that there is a directory located in /media/myusername called "SSH2013-09-16".  I tried to remove it, but rmdir reports "Device or resource busy".  This even happens if I try to remove it with sudo.  Does anyone know what this directory is for, if it should be there, and if not, how I can remove it?

Thanks!

Note: I am running Ubuntu 12.10 64bit Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved It!  Although my cd drive was empty, /dev/sr0 was still mounted to that location.  By going to the file manager and clicking the eject button, it unmounted it.  It seems to me like an Ubuntu bug since there was nothing in my cd tray (and there hasn't been for two days now).  Using the "mount" (as root without arguments) command was helpful to me since it listed all the current mounts.

Comment: You can enter `mount` in terminal or open the system monitors filesystem tab to get an overview of mounted filesystem/devices. Kudos for confusing people by including "SSH" in the name of the mountpoint and non-deliberately confusing people. :)

Answer (score 1):

Always that a device is automagically mounted, the system uses this kind of path to do this. When a device is removed without properly unmounted, this can be happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you mounted an ssh folder ans it's still used.
you should try unmounting it first

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It got me thinking that it might be an old mount, so I tried the mount command.  Apparently Ubuntu hadn't recognized that the cd had been removed a few days ago.  See my answer for more details.  It wasn't an ssh mount, but it got me looking in the right place.